# PDO метод execute() не работает, и ошибок не выдает

Tags: php, sql, pdo, execute

Всем привет, хех. Вообщем если не трудно подскажите в чем может быть проблема, метод execute ничего не сохраняет в БД не выдаёт ошибок и возвращает false, что вроде как очень странно потому что код вроде как правильный (его прикрепляю ниже).

```
public static function createProduct($options)
    {

        $db = Db::getConnection();

        $sql = "INSERT INTO product "
                . "(name, code, price, category_id, brand, availability, "
                . "description, is_new, is_recommended, status) "
                . "VALUES "
                . "(:name, :code, :price, :category_id, :brand, :availability, "
                . ":description, :is_new, :is_recommended, :status)";

        $result = $db->prepare($sql);
        $result->bindParam(':name', $options['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->bindParam(':code', $options['code'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $result->bindParam(':price', $options['price'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->bindParam(':category_id', $options['category_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $result->bindParam(':brand', $options['brand'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->bindParam(':availability', $options['availability'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $result->bindParam(':description', $options['description'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->bindParam(':is_new', $options['is_new'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $result->bindParam(':is_recommended', $options['is_recommended'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $result->bindParam(':status', $options['status'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

        if ($result->execute()) {
            return $db->lastInsertId();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: *execute ничего не сохраняет в БД* Посмотрите текст запроса после вставки параметров. *не выдаёт ошибок* Он-то, может, и выдаёт (не зря же возвращается FALSE!) - это Вы не смотрите сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: Есть два вопроса "почему не выдаёт ошибку и как посмотреть ошибку" и второй вопрос "в чём причина" и на второй без первого не ответить. Давайте в этой теме сконцентрируемся на первой части, а когда вам выдаст текст ошибки - вы создадите другой вопрос (если понадобится -- а то может настолько очевидно будет, что и не надо спрашивать).

Answer (score 0):

Все из-за невнимательности. В БД у меня был еще столбец без значения по умолчанию (image) , а в запросе выше этот столбец не указан, видимо поэтому и не добавлялось.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (!$result) {
    echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
    print_r($db->errorInfo());
}
```

Попробуйте и посмотрите, что вам скажет

Comment: Все из-за невнимательности. В БД у меня был еще столбец без значения по умолчанию (image) , а в запросе выше этот столбец не указан, видимо поэтому и не добавлялось. Спасибо)